# A way to disable "type argument inference" in generics?

Tags: typescript

I was hoping that giving a default value to a generic will take precedence over type inference, but it doesn't:

```
// placeholder for a real express response.send
const sendResponse =  (x) => console.log(x);

function sendResult<T = never>(send: any, result: T) {
  send(result);
}

// I want to use this always with a type
type Num = { x: number };
sendResult<Num>(sendResponse, { x: 1 });
sendResult<Num>(sendResponse, { x: 'sss' }); // correctly showing error

// When I don't supply type, I'd like an error.
// But, T gets inferred instead of defaulting to never... so, no error :-(
sendResult(sendResponse, {x: 1})
```

[See demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=%2F%2F%20placeholder%20for%20a%20real%20express%20response.send%0D%0Aconst%20sendResponse%20%3D%20%20(x)%20%3D%3E%20console.log(x)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20sendResult%3CT%20%3D%20never%3E(send%3A%20any%2C%20result%3A%20T)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20send(result)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20I%20want%20to%20use%20this%20always%20with%20a%20type%0D%0Atype%20Num%20%3D%20%7B%20x%3A%20number%20%7D%3B%0D%0AsendResult%3CNum%3E(sendResponse%2C%20%7B%20x%3A%201%20%7D)%3B%0D%0AsendResult%3CNum%3E(sendResponse%2C%20%7B%20x%3A%20'sss'%20%7D)%3B%20%2F%2F%20correctly%20showing%20error%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20But%2C%20when%20I%20don's%20supply%20type%2C%20I'd%20like%20an%20error.%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Shouldn't%20T%20default%20to%20never%3F%0D%0AsendResult(sendResponse%2C%20%7Bx%3A%201%7D))

Is there a way to make sure an error is thrown if generic is not provided?

Typescript version: 3.5.2

Comment: What is the use case for this ? Why don't you want inference to happen ? `{x: 1}` and `Num` are equivalent types.

Comment: I want to force anybody who uses `sendResult` to provide a type they expect to send.
Inference causes anything to pass IF a <type> is not provided. I want more type safety ;-)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I don't understand the use case, since disabling behavior that TypeScript users expect is probably going to cause confusion.  But you're the boss.

There is an existing GitHub suggestion at [microsoft/TypeScript#14829](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829) to allow a developer to indicate that a particular use of a generic type parameter should not be used for inference.  There is no official support for this, but I think we can simulate it by taking advantage of the compiler's behavior when looking at [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) that depend on an unresolved generic type parameter:

```
type NoInfer<T> = [T][T extends any ? 0 : never];
```

That is essentially a no-op on `T`, since any value you plug in (say `string`) will come out the other side: `[string][string extends any ? 0 : never]` becomes `[string][0]` becomes `string`.  But the compiler sees `T extends any` and decides to defer the calculation until after `T` gets resolved.  In particular, it can't use the value to infer `T` from that.

So then we can try

```
function sendResult<T = never>(send: any, result: NoInfer<T>) {
  send(result);
}
```

And see how it behaves:

```
type Num = { x: number };
sendResult<Num>(sendResponse, { x: 1 }); // okay
sendResult<Num>(sendResponse, { x: "sss" }); // error

sendResult(sendResponse, { x: 1 }); // error
```

The first two cases work as you want because specifying `Num` gives `T` a definite value, and `NoInfer<Num>` is just `Num`.  In the last case, the compiler really has no viable inference site for `T` and thus it has to fall back to the default `never`, and you get your desired error.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEAcBsEMGMFMAWB7SATeAnUAzZ3pRN5pJR4APcYgZxqPhvGQDsb4A6dltAWAChYrGgBdQ3NACVGzNvFABeUAAoKALlDQWATwCUigHyghbVJ0jIA5qt0BuAQJHbw8gHLIAkixxYAPABUjJQBtfwBdUPIKEXgeei1tUAB+UAAGUA0WeAA3LDD7fgEcAFcWWBEAS1ZxWKlGYsgRAMVQLNzMA2UJDQSAGgYaBpENdy8fTACDfQBvAVAanmVaIbsBAF8HficXUFdigFsW6dB1VoOAIyxQNYKJaUHG3z39zruZYXh+49OARmu7UAgUDIADW0G0AjeDyaz1etXusnYXxOGgARHQaKj-rZAWAsJh8JsoUMuvD3nJkb9sbjyJgCZgBEA)

So that works as you want, but remember that you might want to rethink this idea, since people who get that error might be confused about what the heck they're supposed to do to make the error go away.  People rely on type inference, so you'll need some great documentation if you proceed with this.

Comment: I wonder though without any official support for something like this how much it can be relied upon. It is conceivable that in the future the compiler might try to be smarter about reasoning about conditional types, and be able to work out that  `NoInfer<T>` is just `T`. I was thinking about using function currying (somthing like `sendResult()(sendResponse, {x: 1})` where `T` is on `sendResult`) but then I remembered Anders mentioning that they might try to infer `T` in such cases as well in the future. Great solution though 

Comment: Presumably there will always be some way to tell the compiler to defer resolution since some things do depend on it, but I agree that details could change so that this particular `NoInfer` will stop working and we'd have to do something else to address it.  ‍♂️

Comment: Wow, smart answer, thanks @jcalz!
1. I think that type inference is not something people *always* want or expect.
2. I wonder what is the point of being able to provide defaults to generics (like `<T = never>`) - when they get overridden by inference anyway. Do the defaults do something?

Comment: The [documentation for this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#generic-parameter-defaults) indicates that the default is chosen when the type can't be inferred.  That would happen with optional function parameters like `function foo<T=U>(x?: T): void` where you call `foo()`.  I've more often used defaults in generic *types* like `type Foo<T=U> = {x: T}` where just `Foo` means `Foo<U>`.

Comment: They also kick in when you have multiple type parameters and only specify some (no partial type inference, at least not yet) ex: https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcA8AVANIgqogXkQGcoAnGMAcwD4AKKALkW0RGdwEpEBvRAXwBQKOHQAMWMdwD00xHADWiYajRgQAWwBGAUzL0JiKYll5EMYiXKUqQA

Comment: I've seen it impact Intellisense, where defining a function's argument list as a derived tuple of string constants can blow up when you first type `foo('')`. Wrapping your tuple generator in `NoInfer` prevents Intellisense from prematurely trying to derive your parameter suggestions from `''` and blowing up.

Answer (score 2):

## Updated answer

The utility type `NoInfer` is now implemented as an intrinsic type in Typescript 5.4. Yay!

---

## Old answer

The most modern solution to this appears to be the following utility type:

```
type NoInfer<T> = T extends infer U ? U : never;
```